# Create local postgreSQL database with back up from database in Server

Tags: database, postgresql

In a project that I support, we already have PostgreSQL database in different environments - Development, Integration and. production.
I know we can take a back up of Integration database with PG_Dump and restore it to Development in order to sync those databases.

However, I want to understand if I can use the back up file from PG_dump to create the database locally in my system?

Comment: 1,Why you need to sync local database with the online?

Comment: Sure, a local database is in no way different from a remote one. Do you encounter any problems? If, yes, please describe them [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64601419/edit).

Comment: @Spikie This is a new application that I am supporting and I would like to create a local database using the backup of the database in the server, specifically Development. So that I could debug it locally.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe There is no specific problem, I just wanted to know if I can use the backup file from the database in the server and create it in my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "local database" is not substantially different from a "remote database", so yes, that should work.

As always, note that restoring a dump on a lower PostgreSQL version than the one where it was taken is not supported (and will often fail).